# Can I use a directive to calculate field value based on other field value?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma

I have such a model:

```
type Email {
  id: ID! @unique
  confirmed: Boolean! @default(value: "false")
  formatted: String! @unique
  raw: String!
}
```

I need to lowercase value from `raw` field and put it into `formatted` field before saving to db.

The thing is that I have already three use cases (contact us, subscribe to news, signup) and I’ll need to write the same code in three different resolvers.

To avoid duplication I thought it would be nice to do this in a directive somehow.

Is it possible to create my own directive which would handle this?

**Update: As of Prisma v1.18 it's not possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Prisma and indeed needs to be implemented on the application layer. There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2747) for this though, please join the discussion on GitHub and add your +1 if you're interested in this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the spec doc, I don't think it is possible (unfortunately) because that sounds like you need a computed field

"GraphQL is not a programming language capable of arbitrary computation, but is instead a language used to query application servers that have capabilities defined in this specification."

https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/